# different colors on ComboBox

Tags: codenameone

I was testing a ComboBox in my device and I noticed gray stripes that where not there before. The stripes don't show on the simulator.

I changed the UIID for the ComboBox from white to yellow to check if it was the background color, but it is still there.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are running on the nexus skin on the simulator which uses an older native theme as a basis, this is probably the cause of the difference between your device and the Simulator, change your simulator to HTCOne or xoom and you will most likely see these stripes on the simulator as well.

Try to modify the "ComboBoxItem" uiid to be transparent and with an empty border

Comment: it worked. Thanks Chen. Any chance to have a Galaxy skin in the  simulator?

Comment: We have a plan to improving the skin situation ideally in a 3.5 timeframe